# Comware 7 - User Accounts Close Every 5 Days

Tags: authentication, 3-com, hp-comware

A coworker and I recently migrated a core from old Dell switches to two `HP 5700` running Comware 7 and IRF. What we have noticed is that every 5 days, the user accounts no longer accept the passwords. Even if no unsuccessful attempts were made whatsoever, all of the accounts lock every 5 days. We only have HTTPS and SSH protocols enabled for remote access over the VTY lines. What we find is that, when we enter the wrong password, it asks us to re-enter the correct one. However, once we do, it simply terminates the connection.

The only way that I have found to fix it is by getting physical, console access, deleting the accounts, and re-creating them. Is there a way to fix this?

Unfortunately, this is a sensitive client, so I will not be able to post the entire configuration, but I can post certain parts upon request:

VTY Line configuration:

```
line vty 0 4
  authentication-mode scheme
  user-role network-admin
  user-role network-operator
  set authentication password hash $h$6$[password omitted]
  protocol inbound ssh
```

Local User Admin:

```
local-user admin class manage
  access-limit 100
  service-type ssh terminal https
  authorization-attribute user-role network-admin
  authorization-attribute user-role network-operator
  password-control aging 90
  password-control login-attempt 10 exceed lock-time 1
```

Local User User1:

```
Local-user user1 class manage
  access-limit 3
  service-type ssh terminal https
  authorization-attribute user-role network-admin
  authorization-attribute user-role network-operator
```

Local User User2:

```
local-user user2 class manage
  service-type ssh https
  authorization-attribute user-role network-admin
  authorization-attribute user-role network-operator
```

Thank you.

Comment: `display password-control` and `display password-control blacklist` may shed some light on it. Based on what you've provided, they shouldn't expire for 90 days. And the default setup does allow expired users to still login -- the change the password. (consult the HP FlexFabric 5700 Security Configuration Guide, there may be other AAA configuration in there.)